# How to sove this inequality: $2 \cdot \sqrt{x^2-x-2} -2x +1 > 0$. I know it looks obvious, but there something into it

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I get $-8>1$, which mean that $2\sqrt{x^2-x-2} -2x +1 > 0$ is always false , but actually it isn't.

Edit: here is how I got it.

$2\sqrt{x^2-x-2} -2x +1 > 0  $

$2\sqrt{x^2-x-2} > 2x -1 $

$(2\sqrt{x^2-x-2})^2 > (2x -1)^2 $

$4x^2 -4x -8 > 4x^2 -4x +1 $

$4x^2 -4x -8 - 4x^2 + 4x>   +1 $

$ -8 > +1 $

Comment: 1. Can you share your work? 2. $-8>1$ is false, not true.

Comment: Your question would be greatly improved if you explained the method you used to get to the inequality $-8 > 1$; then we might be able to see where you went wrong.

Comment: I updated the post, thanks for checking in.

Comment: $a>b$ does not correspond to $a^2>b^2$ unless $a, b$ both positive or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check the domain of this inequality. Since the quantity under the radical must not be negative, the domain is the solution set of
$$x^2 - x - 2 \ge 0
$$
which is
$$x \in (-\infty,-1] \cup [2,+\infty)
$$
Next let's check each of the two pieces of this domain.

On the piece $x \in (-\infty,-1]$, the left hand side of the inequality is $\ge 0$ (because square roots are always $\ge 0$), and the right hand side is negative. So the inequality is true for all $x \in (-\infty,-1]$.

On the piece $x \in [2,\infty)$, both sides of the inequality are positive. Your method therefore applies, to prove that your inequality is equivalent to the false inequality $-8>1$ (you need to carefully justify the step where you squared both sides: but squaring both sides of an inequality of positive numbers does produce an equivalent inequality). So the inequality is false for all $x \in [2,\infty)$.

The solution set is therefore $(-\infty,-1]$.

Comment: That was a clear explanation. Thank you for you help I appreciate it.